# Android studio 2.0 gradle transformClassesWithDexForDebug fails when using button "run"

Tags: gradle, android-studio-2.0

I have a problem after migration from android studio 1.5 to 2.0

In one of my project (only one) i can't use android studio run button,

because then, build fails on gradle task "transformClassesWithDexForDebug"

with error:

```
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local variable type mismatch: attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int. This is symptomatic of .class transformation tools that ignore local variable information.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:425)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:365)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.runDexer(AndroidBuilder.java:1473)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibraryNoCache(AndroidBuilder.java:1659)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:119)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1614)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:475)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:429)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.runDexer(AndroidBuilder.java:1457)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$2.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1465)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$2.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1457)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
    ... 2 more
```

what is even more frustrating, this is not happening when I am using terminal command where are the same gradle tasks

```
./gradlew clean generateDebugSources generateDebugAndroidTestSources mockableAndroidJar prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies assembleDebug
```

The apk files are nicely generated
Problem appears on MAC and Linux, so it is not platform specified, but it not appears in Android Studio 1.5

I am posting my gradle.build file

Many thanks in advance

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }


    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.wojtek.MyProject"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 4
            versionName "0.1.3"
            testInstrumentationRunner 'com.wojtek.my_project.AndroidTestRunner'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }

        testOptions {

            unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$support_version"
        compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$support_version"
        compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$support_version"
        compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$support_version"
        compile "com.android.support:design:$support_version"
        compile "com.android.support:palette-v7:$support_version"

        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        compile "io.reactivex:rxkotlin:$rx_kotlin"
        compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:$anko_version"
        compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.1'

        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
        compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$retrofitVersion"

        apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
        compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
        provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'


        //TEST******************************************************************************************
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

        androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$support_version"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESSPRESSO_VERSION"

    androidTestCompile ("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESSPRESSO_VERSION"){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'

    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'

    androidTestApt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"


}
```

Comment: See this **[guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42975471/7756492)** here to fix. I hope this will help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

for few weeks i was trying to solve this problem.

Now I have found workaround for that. If someone face the same problem, turning off instant Run in Android Studio settings will help.

I know that it is not a solution but it is the best thing for now.

cheers
Wojtek

Comment: Man, thank you. It solved my problem. It looks like a problem with native libraries (JNI). It is sad that I had to disable it, but at least it works. I just noticed that on manual gradlew build works (probably because it doesnt trigger instant run)

Comment: Sigh. I still have this problem in *ONE* of my modules, even after turning off Instant Run, disabling proguard, running from the command-line, invalidating caches and restarting, and rebooting. I have stripped out everything non-trivial and it still happens. Sigh. AS is a PoS.

Answer (score 9):

add

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

in android

Answer (score 5):

I restart Android Studio (2.0) when I have this problem. Then it works. No edit in gradle files or turn off instant run required.

Comment: really? you think that i haven't re run AS , but i tried to run in on 3 different machines? great answer indeed

Comment: i can give you upvote because my code run after restart

Answer (score 3):

All it took to fix this issue for me was to add the following lines to the build.gradle file for the mobile app:

...

android {

```
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

...
```

}

dependencies {

```
...

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

...
```

}

Answer (score 2):

For me adding this line (or commenting out because it is written there in the 13th line) in `gradle.properties` worked:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Also I turned off Instant run (Android Studio 2.1.2).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, on linux. For some reason, some files and dirs inside /build can not be deleted, not even with 'sudo -rf', and this is the origin of the problem for me. I built the project in a MacBookPro and no problem.

Comment: i tried to do it on MacBook as well, the problem still occurs. Maybe will try on windows :P thx

Comment: Can you manually delete /build contents before run and see what happens?

Comment: tried it as well. tried delete whole project from disk and pull it again from repo. On 3 different computers...  no changes

Answer (score 1):

`attempt to set or access a value of type java.lang.Object using a local variable of type int`

Seems like in some place ProGuard optimizes variable allocation, but does it incorrectly.

Try to disable this optimization by adding the line below in your `proguard-rules.pro`:

`-optimizations !code/allocation/variable`

Comment: sure, in debug mode ;-)

Comment: Oh, my bad. You don't use the minification in debug mode, don't you? :) But for some people who use ProGuard, my answer may help.

Comment: maybe. I belive that it is problem with Dagger2 build time classes and instant run, but i don't have time to check it ;P

Answer (score 1):

**Refactoring** the library helped me resolving this issue. This must have helped in removing duplicate classes from the **library** or from the **app** module.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered many solutions but I solved this issue by adding:

**Sol 1:** In `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Clean your project and rebuild.

**Sol 2:** If still you have issue in `local.properties` add,

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

**Sol 3** Still, You have issue add below mentioned dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Anyone solution will definitely work for you. **Otherwise add all 3 in your application.**

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer might work, but I'll share what fixed this with me. It was due to the maximum number of methods being reached after the addition of an additional library dependency.

See [this guide here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) to fix, skip down to **Configuring Your App for Multidex with Gradle** section to get to the point.

Comment: It has nothing to do with multidex, but thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, but this developer.android.come guide worked out for me:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

It says the following:

If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your module-level build.gradle file, as `enter code here`shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

However, if your minSdkVersion is set to 20 or lower, then you must use the multidex support library as follows:

Modify the module-level build.gradle file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25  

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Just set this in your app's build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,

1. In build.gradle,
   put your current android version as example 3.0.1

   dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:**3.0.1**'}
2. In gradle-wrapper.properties,
   change your gradle version as example gradle-4.4
   distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/**gradle-4.4**-all.zip

I hope this can help!

Answer (score -1):

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ... }

    dependencies {   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' }

    repositories {
    mavenCentral() }


    <application    ...
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"> </application>
```

Comment: <application
    android:largeHeap=“true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
</application>