# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug' in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, runtimeexception

I am moving my projects from eclipse to Android Studio. While running one of my app I get the following error. Not able to find any solution. I have enabled multidex as well.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

also my gradle file is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled true
}buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard- android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt', 'proguard-google-api-client.txt'
     }
   }
 }
 dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
 compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-cardview.jar')
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-appengine:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-appengine:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.18.0-rc'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-appengine:1.18.0-rc'
compile files('libs/google-api-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jackson2-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-http-client-jdo-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-servlet-1.18.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/GraphView-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-6.1.26.jar')
compile files('libs/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar')
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
compile files('libs/jxl.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
compile files('libs/transaction-api-1.1.jar')
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045129/android-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1)

Comment: In the latest version 3.2 of AS, missing resource files may also cause this problem.I don't know if you have this problem.It only suggests that: aapt "finished with non-zero exit value 1 "and not explicit like other version.

Answer (score 73):

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 1

The upper error occure due to lot of reason. So I can put why this error occure and how to solve it.

**REASON 1 :** Duplicate of class file name

**SOLUTION :**

when your refactoring of some of your class files to a library project. and that time you write name of class file So, double check that you do not have any duplicate names

**REASON 2 :** When you have lot of cache Memory

**SOLUTION :**

Sometime if you have lot of cache memory then this error occure so solve it.
go to `File/Invalidate caches / Restart` then select `Invalidate and Restart` it will clean your cache memory.

**REASON 3 :** When there is internal bug or used beta Version to Switch back to stable version.

**SOLUTION :**

Solution is just simple go to Build menu and click `Clean Project` and after cleaning click `Rebuild Project`.

**REASON 4 :** When you memory of the system Configuration is low.

**SOLUTION :**

open Task Manager and stop the other application which are not most used at that time so it will free the space and solve `OutOfMemory`.

**REASON 5 :** The problem is your method count has exceed from 65K.

**SOLUTION :**

open your Project `build.gradle` file add

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

and in dependencies add below line.

```
dependencies 
    {
       compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: if you have already add  multiDexEnabled true then REASON-2 is help you. Thanks @Ironman , its help me.

Comment: @Nils glad to know that.

Comment: How can I find methods count?

Comment: I had to uncomment org.gradle.jvmargs in graddle.properties

Comment: thanks @Ironman for pointing out these solutions.Some times I am getting this error even if i have multiDexEnabled true, solution 2 help on that case.Otherwise I need to restart my machine to solve this.

Comment: Cleaning the project worked for me. I restarted both my computer and phones several times and rebooted android studio and nothing helped except cleaning >.<

Comment: invalidate cache and restart worked for me... guys do this option very first try... Thanks

Comment: Android 5.0 (API level 21) and higher uses ART which natively supports multidexing. Therefore, if your `minSdkVersion` is 21 or higher, the multidex support library is not needed.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

Answer (score 11):

**In my case problem solved with Instant Run DISABLE **[image]

Answer (score 8):

Check Whether multidex enabled or not in your **build.gradle(app level)** under dependencies.if not place like below

```
dependecies{
multidexEnabled true
}
```

Check your gradle.properties(app level).if you see the below code

```
#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

remove # before the line ,then it should be like this

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 5):

Please
Add this into your gradle file

```
android {
...
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

AND also add the below dependency in your gradle

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

OR another option would be: In your manifest file add the MultiDexApplication package from the multidex support library in the application tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be because of following reason:

1. one of the jar files inside project was using an older version of google play services.
2. use `multiDexEnabled true` in `defaultconfig`
3. Be specific with classes you add in dependencies. like

   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

Not like compile `'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything but still this error won't go, until I **changed my JDK version**.

My JDK version was 7, and after I changed it to 8, the error went away, you can try it if nothing else works.

Answer (score 1):

i have tried this one and it worked for me.
hope it works for others too.

1. Open build.gradle module file
2. downgrade you sdkversion from 25 to 24 or 23
3. add 'multiDexEnabled true'
4. comment this line : compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0' (if it's in 'dependencies')
5. Sync your project
   and ready to go.

Here i have attached screenshot to explain things.
[Go through this steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuy7d.png)

happy to help.

thanks.

Comment: Downgrading the sdkversion is a bad idea. The Google Play Store  even require you to up you sdkversion in the future.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution is to place the code below in the module `build.gradle` :

```
android { 
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}
```

And Sync the Project.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this -

```
Extend your Application class with MultiDexApplication instead of Application !
```

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate name Classes

like

```
class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
```

and

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
```

Answer (score 1):

i have tried this one for more projects and it worked for me. note that solution can configure your app for multidex:

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 25
     buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

     defaultConfig {
           ...
           minSdkVersion 9
           targetSdkVersion 25
     }

     buildTypes {
          release {
              shrinkResources true
              minifyEnabled true
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
          }
     }}

 dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
       ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank @Ironman for his complete answer, however I should add my solution according to what I've experienced facing this issue.

In build.gradle (Module: app):

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    ...

    dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }

    ...

    defaultConfig {
            multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Also, put the following in gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m -XX\:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding\=UTF-8
```

I should mention, these numbers are for my laptop config (MacBook Pro with 16 GB RAM) therefore please edit them as your config.

Answer (score 0):

My Settings Screenshot:
[image]

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593582/android-studio-2-0-gradle-transformclasseswithdexfordebug-fails-when-using-butto).

Just turn off instant run in your settings. You can easily search the keyword "instant" like I showed and it would switch to the window you want.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had 2 projects `A` and `B`. And I upgraded to `gradle 4.5`.

`A` was dependent on `B` but both had references of my `3rd party jar`

I was getting this error

> com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already
>   present: com.mnox.webservice.globals.WebServiceLightErrorHashCode
>
> > Program type already present: com.mnox.webservice.globals.WebServiceLightErrorHashCode

To fix it

1. I removed the duplicate jar's
2. I used `api` in the `B` build.gradle file so that it gets referred to in `A`.

The other root cause can be if you have upgraded to `gradle 4.5` and used `implementation` instead of `api` in your commons `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Just worth mentioning that while others suggest tempering with files, I was able to resolve this issue by installing a missing plugin (ionic framework)

Hopefully it helps someone.

cordova plugin add cordova-support-google-services --save

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to delete the gradle cache folder (.gradle/caches) in the home directory and build again. Possibly due to a duplicate class loading issue.

Answer (score 0):

**For Ionic 4 Just**

```
$ cordova clean
```

Helped me then run

```
$ ionic cordova run android --device
```