# Android studio - transformClassesWithDexForDebug error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Here is my graddle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/' }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    //Support Library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    //Test
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'
    //Common Langs 3
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
    //Google Cloud Translate
    compile ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:0.7.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    //Ksoap 2
    compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.2'
    //Gson (Shared Preferences)
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    //Loading Animation
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.7'
    //Snackbar
    compile 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
    //SVG Animation
    compile 'com.jaredrummler:animated-svg-view:1.0.0'
}
```

Here is the Androidmanifest.xmlpart

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashAnimationActivity"
```

Here is the android studio error:

```
   Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.
Error:trouble processing "javax/transaction/HeuristicCommitException.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Information:Total time: 46.622 secs
Information:34 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

I am working on a google cloud translate application. 
I am getting errors.

I search and ı have try some solution but does not help me.

What isthe problem ?

My libs folder is empty.

please help me.

Comment: did you initialize the multidex?

Comment: check out  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497882/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-in-androi/37498940#37498940

Answer (score 1):

I had a same issue. In my app I am using guava-retrying library, which was fetching google guava library version 21. **Guava version 21** requires JDK 1.8 without providing back porting support and this was causing this error in my case.

I was able to solve it by including the guava-retrying library so that it uses version 19.0 of guava library:

```
compile ("com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:2.0.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

Basically you would want to check if any of your app's dependencies require JDK 1.8 to compile, and remove/downgrade them.