# How to resolve duplicate entry error while run project

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Here is my build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.demo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
    aaptOptions
            {
                cruncherEnabled = false
            }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':draggerLibrary')
    compile project(':staggeredGridViewmaster')



    compile files('libs/httpclientandroidlib-1.2.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4-beta1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    compile project(':viewPagerLibrary')
    compile project(path: ':ViewPagerLibrary')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'

    compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'
    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.6'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
}
```

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':DemoProject:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     android/support/v4/provider/DocumentsContractApi19.class

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497882/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-in-androi/37498040#37498040

Comment: use `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'` and `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Thnks for answer . if i going to use 11.0.2 than i got error like 
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

Comment: @ashish `compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`

Comment: @ashish use `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` .After that clean-Rebuild and RUN

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : i resolved that error but i can not get object like 
googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
     R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: @Dipalishah : I have already configure my build that you mentioned in answer. Thnks for answer

Comment: @ashish kindly check my answer .Hope it will works

Answer (score 3):

Configure your **`build.gradle`** .

**Use**

```
compileSdkVersion 25 
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
```

**Then**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2' 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

For your **MAP** problem use **getMapAsync()**

```
 SupportMapFragment mapOBJ = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
  mapOBJ.getMapAsync(this);
```

Read **[Replace getMap with getMapAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371865/replace-getmap-with-getmapasync)**

Comment: Now again i got same error after as you mentioned in this answer.

Comment: i have update my question ->build.gradle file as you suggest me for changes.

Comment: @ashish That's mean Same problem coming ?

Comment: Yes if you want screen shot of my log i can give you actually i have import this project from eclipse.

Comment: Information:BUILD SUCCESSFUL , But when i run the app at that point i got same error