# Gradle error when i make a Build Apk in android studio, but am able to run on devices not able to generate apk file through Build Apk

Tags: android, build.gradle

Build apk is throwing this issue but am able to run on devices not able to generate apk file through Build Apk. just months before it was good and i was able to make a build apk, but after few updates i am getting the below build issue. I searched on internet alot but nothing is working for me I have posted the message below and the build.gradle file too.

gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1563M
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE'
        exclude 'NOTICE'
        exclude 'NOTICE.txt'
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    /*configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }*/

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.2.0'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.0.2'){
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
        exclude module: 'stax'
        exclude module: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'
    compile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3"
    compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Error Message:

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:mobile:assembleDevDebug]
    Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
    Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    Error:  at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
    Error:  at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.utf8BytesToString(CstString.java:158)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstString.<init>(CstString.java:200)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseUtf8(ConstantPoolParser.java:371)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse0(ConstantPoolParser.java:262)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parse(ConstantPoolParser.java:150)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.parseIfNecessary(ConstantPoolParser.java:124)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.cst.ConstantPoolParser.getPool(ConstantPoolParser.java:115)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:491)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:772)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1700)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:755)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:723)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1653)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:677)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:569)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:366)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:275)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    Error:  at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    Error:Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
    Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list D:\AndStudio\AndroidStudioProjects\Matrix\mobile\build\intermediates\multi-dex\dev\debug\maindexlist.txt --output D:\AndStudio\AndroidStudioProjects\Matrix\mobile\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\dev\debug\folders\1000\1f\main D:\AndStudio\AndroidStudioProjects\Matrix\mobile\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\dev\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}
    Information:BUILD FAILED
    Information:Total time: 4 mins 38.409 secs
    Information:33 errors
    Information:0 warnings
    Information:See complete output in console
```

a solution to this would be great and thank to all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497882/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-in-androi

check this link, hope it helps

Comment: @Arpit thanks for your reply but i have already tried the above link it didnt worked any of the solution. my system is 4 GB ram it was working good last month but suddenly after some updates or what happened i dont know its throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this google service version and check

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87
```